# Fixed table header widths break if there is at least one table header row above them

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I'm using the table component from the Vuetify framework. I'm building a dynamic table, based on a configuration, so I don't know how many columns there will be. The fixed table headers are dynamic ( width is coming from configuration ) and might be nested inside a parent group or might have a rowspan greater than 1.

This code here ( [playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) ) shows a table as I would expect it

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-table fixed-header>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- column width coming from configuration file -->
            <th
              :colspan="1"
              :rowspan="1"
              :style="{ width: `${300}px` || 'auto' }"
            >
              Col 1
            </th>
            <!-- column width coming from configuration file -->
            <th
              :colspan="1"
              :rowspan="1"
              :style="{ width: `${20}px` || 'auto' }"
            >
              Col 2
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td :rowspan="2">Col 1, Rowspan 2</td>
            <td :rowspan="1">Col 2, Rowspan 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td :rowspan="1" class="d-none">Col 1, Rowspan 1</td>
            <td :rowspan="1">Col 2, Rowspan 1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
  .v-table__wrapper table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0 !important;
  }

  .v-table {
    flex: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
  }
</style>
```

The output looks fine

[image]

but whenever the configuration contains header groups the widths break. When I add the following table header row above the other one ( [playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
      <tr>
        <!-- column width is the sum of child column widths -->
        <th
          :colspan="2"
          :rowspan="1"
          :style="{ width: `${320}px` || 'auto' }"
        >
          Group Col
        </th>
      </tr>
```

I get this output

[image]

although I would expect the first column to have a width of 300 and the second one to have a width of 20.

---

Sidenote: I'm facing less issues when reproducing it with plain HTML

- Single header row => [playground link](https://jsfiddle.net/t18ckf4p/)
- Header row with group => [playground link](https://jsfiddle.net/m8tqcbjx/)

---

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<colgrup>` to size the columns: ([playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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))

```html
 <v-table fixed-header>
        <colgroup>
          <col :style="{ width: `${300}px` || 'auto' }" />
          <col :style="{ width: `${20}px` || 'auto' }" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- column width is the sum of child column widths -->
            <th :colspan="2" :rowspan="1" class="text-center">Group Col</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <!-- column width coming from configuration file -->
            <th :colspan="1" :rowspan="1" class="text-center">Col 1</th>
            <!-- column width coming from configuration file -->
            <th :colspan="1" :rowspan="1" class="text-center">Col 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td :rowspan="2">Col 1, Rowspan 2</td>
            <td :rowspan="1">Col 2, Rowspan 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td :rowspan="1" class="d-none">Col 1, Rowspan 1</td>
            <td :rowspan="1">Col 2, Rowspan 1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So all you did was removing the widths from the column headers and add this ```<colgroup>
          <col :style="{ width: `${300}px` || 'auto' }" />
          <col :style="{ width: `${20}px` || 'auto' }" />
        </colgroup>``` above the headers, am I correct? Have to try it in my application for the dynamic columns

Comment: @baitendbidz yes, I set widths on `<colgroup>` instead of table cells.

Answer (score 0):

First you have wrong html because when `td` has `rowspan="2"` then the next `tr td` should be one. Second, you can set `min-width: 20px; max-width: 0;` for the last cells:

```css
table td {
  width: 300px;
}

table td:last-child,
table th:last-child {
  min-width: 20px;
  max-width: 0;
}

/* debugging */
table td ,
table th {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Group Col</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Col 1, Rowspan 2</td>
      <td>Col 2, Rowspan 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">Col 1, Rowspan 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Vuetify Play](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqVUl1PgzAU/Su1z+NDZmKCSGJ88N1XMUuBGkiANuUyWJb9d1vaDjo1c28999xzer8+jrgXRfDCub8fKI5xArTlDQGaZh1Cyd4jnM/PGbSk7gyaMZC8oeirnmjpVZSUVJxZyYMKrQIqtE4wSahgTc9J95zhKMPpm2ADR6+sSQKoXHVwIf/VLpVSdP9DvHDRNWPFu5UnkLPycPXvEgk2rlqZK9mgdx2cP3bnMYt0UUuaqv1ibP9p/HYfCZ22ksBs1C5c4vPGFdC3IGXLjUjYw8FIfKPf7UYhc6lA+kCO2m+sS6hiRAZg6K5uORNAOnhS5Ek5LQZIjtIVbcOQT3+kxg3pwSuquik3LlWtKGvY1p1nTCPrKaNkstHQfpMEtjV82uCt/+CHXk6B+BHW8BF/fgO+U+mJ)

Comment: thanks for your reply but the solution won't work for my case. I don't know if there will only be 2 columns, the configuration tells me how many there will be, I have to calculate everything

Comment: This is just an example. You can add inline styles to the desired cell `<td style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 0;"></td>`